# Структура пользователей

Tags: cron, php, mysql

Собственно есть сайт, использует базу данных mysql. Есть задача сделать реферальную систему.

Подробнее. Заходит пользователь приглашает людей, например пригласил человек 10. Так же само эти 10 пригласили еще по 10, а те 100 еще по 10.

Задача вывести пользователю на экран всю его структуру.

Теперь собственно подскажите пожалуйста как хранить структуру. Если просчитывать в реальном времени, то структура в 20 000 человек генерируется около минуты. Это естественно не дело.

Есть идея каждые 20 часа бегать кроном и формировать массив структуры и хранить в бд в типа text. Будет ли это уместно или есть идеи по лучше ? 
(деревья типа NESTED SETS не катит. пересчитывать каждый раз по 100 000 раз ключи не вариант)

Comment: т.е. граф направленный ? это вроде просто. только весь его выводить никакого смысла :)

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: деревья и прочее вообще не вариант. Я натыкался на момент, когда пользователи просили поменять реферала и администратор менял и получалась петля. Я пригласил 3, те 3 по три и 1 из тех пригласил меня. И так сервер ложился от бесконечной рекурсии.

Comment: @NEPSTER а можно было сделать чтобы не зацикливался? )

Comment: да, но у меня было все это дело без дерева и рекурсией, что там стояли проверки на такое дело. НО деревья я пробовал лепить, это вообще не вариант

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, ваша структура суть - дерево. вы никак без деревьев свою задачу не решите :P

Comment: userID, parentID вся суть древовидной структуры. Проставьте индексы на эти поля. Для исключения рекурсии, при изменении реферала делать проверку чтобы исключить кольца.

Answer (score 1):

> Если просчитывать в реальном времени, то структура в 20 000 человек генерируется около минуты

Для формирования дерева пользователя вы строите всю структуру?

На мой взгляд можно к пользователям добавить еще одно поле, которое будет содержать всех его реферальных отцов. Например, запись "[1][12][15]" будет говорить что он зареган по рефералке пользователя с id 15, который зареган по рефералке с id 12, а тот по id 1.

Дальше, для пользователя id=1 делаем выборку записей, где встречается "[1]". И дальше в php можно обработать и преобразовать в дерево.

Comment: А хранить все эти массивы в базе ?

Comment: да, вложенность наверно не такая большая будет. Т.е. это дополнительный столбец

Comment: @IVsevolod Вы предлагаете искать по like ? мб тогда отдельную таблицу ?

Comment: не не никаких лайков, говорят на больших кол-во записей это большое зло. Раньше я просто кроном просчитывал за минут 10 - 20, весь сайт и в отдельную таблицу для каждого пользователя хранил массив из всех user_id его структуры. Однако база разраслась очень быстро. Да пожалуй из минусом это и все

Comment: @eicto можно отдельной табличкой :)